# Knockout asyncCommand - hit from a method

Tags: asynchronous, knockout.js

I want to alter how an asyncCommand is being hit (currently from a button), so I would need to access the asyncCommand from code. I don't want to have to alter what this asyncCommand is doing, it is dealing with payment details.

I have tried Googling but I cant find anything, I am also new to KO.

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

- Click on a button (a separate button with its own asyncCommand method
  which checks a flag) The 'execute' will do the following:

If (flag) - show modal

- modal has two options - Continue / Cancel
- If continue - hit asyncCommand command for original button (card payment one).
- If cancel - go back to form

If (!flag)

- Hit asyncCommand command for original button (card payment one).

Can this be done?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Clare

This is what I have tried:
FIRST BUTTON

```
   model.checkAddress = ko.asyncCommand({
        execute: function (complete)
        {
            makePayment.execute();
            if (data.shippingOutOfArea === true || (data.shippingOutOfArea === null && data.billingOutOfArea === true)) {
                model.OutOfArea.show(true);
            }

            complete();
        },
        canExecute: function (isExecuting) {
            return !isExecuting;
        }
    });
```

ORIGINAL BUTTON

```
    model.makePayment = ko.asyncCommand({
        execute: function (complete) {
}})
```

MODAL

```
model.OutOfArea = {
    header: ko.observable("Out of area"),
    template: "modalOutOfArea",
    closeLabel: "Close",
    primaryLabel: "Continue",
    cancelLabel: "Change Address",
    show: ko.observable(false), /* Set to true to show initially */
    sending: ko.observable(false),
    onClose: function ()
    {
        model.EditEmailModel.show(false);
    },
    onAction: function () {
        makePayment.execute();
    },
    onCancel: function ()
    {
        model.EditEmailModel.show(false);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have two async commands actually for this scenario. One to open up the modal and another one for the modal.

Eg:

```js
showPaymentPromptCmd = ko.asyncCommand({
  execute: function(complete) {
    if (modalRequired) {
      showModal();
    } else {
      makePayement();
    }
    complete();
  },
  canExecute: function(isExecuting) {
    return !isExecuting;
  }
});

//Called by Continue button on your modal.
makePaymentCmd = ko.asyncCommand({
  execute: function(complete) {
    makePayement();
    complete();
  },
  canExecute: function(isExecuting) {
    return !isExecuting;
  }
});

var

function makePayement() {
  //some logic
}
```